How do I communicate between hosted components in a micro frontend system?
I have 2 microfront ends, one hosts component for interacting with a file system (call this MFE_docs), the other interacts with a user record system (call this MFE_recs).
In MFE_docs I am exposing a component to view a list of files:
export class Document  {
    public isSelected: boolean = false;
    id: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'document-view',
    standalone: true,
    template: `
        <table>
            <!-- Code for table header -->
            <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
                <span>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="{{row.id}}" name="{{row.id}}-select" value="false" [disabled]="false" (change)="onSelectRow(row)" />
                </span>
                <!-- More code to display other columns -->
            </tr>
        </table>
    `
})
export class DocumentViewComponent {
    @Output() documentSelect = new EventEmitter<Document>();
    @Output() documentDeselect = new EventEmitter<Document>();
    @Output() documentSelectionChange = new EventEmitter<Document[]>();

    rows = new BehaviorSubject<Document[]>([]); // There is code that I've omitted which populates this

    public getSelected(): Document[] {
        return this.rows.value
            .filter((row: Document) => row.isSelected);
    }

    onSelectRow(document: Document) {
        document.isSelected = !document.isSelected;
        if (document.isSelected) {
            this.documentSelect.emit(document);
        } else {
            this.documentDeselect.emit(document);
        }

        this.documentSelectionChange.emit(this.getSelected());
    }
}

In MFE_recs I have a form where I can edit a user record and then link files to that record:
@Component({
    selector: 'record-edit-form',
    standalone: true,
    template: `
        <!-- Code for user record form -->
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
export class RecordEditFormComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    onSelectRow(document: Document) {
        // How do I call this from DocumentViewComponent?
    }
}

I want to use DocumentViewComponent in MFE_recs, so I've configured app.routes.ts like this:
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'users/:id/view',
        loadComponent: () => import('./record-edit-form.component').then((mod) => mod.RecordEditFormComponent),
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                loadComponent: () =>
                    import('./documents/document-view/document-view.component').then(
                        (mod) => mod.DocumentViewComponent
                    )
            }
        ]
    }
]

This works and I can see the document-view component in the user records front end.  What I'm unsure on is how do I bind on to the events coming from DocumentViewComponent, or call methods on it, or anything like that?  In other examples in the code base the functionality of the MFE component is totally self contained so it works just fine, but I can't find any examples of how to share data (beyond a url) or invoke code between them.
As a follow up question; is doing this even a good idea?  The user record MFE and document MFE make sense to split into different services as they have different teams and different purposes, but I'm not sure how you are supposed to handle situation like this where some degree of tight coupling is required?
